# React Router not loading any pages

Tags: reactjs, webpack-4

I can't seem to make the routing work. URL does change but the page doesn't. The router doesn't find the match for some reason.
I am a custom configuration for webpack. I am not using create-react-app.
Another version with the project created with create-react-app works fine tho.
I need the custom configuration for the small bundle size it offers.

My webpack configuration:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: ['./src/index.js'],
    devtool: 'cheal-module-source-map',
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader" },
            {
                test: /\.s?css$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader',
                    'sass-loader'
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: 'public/index.html'
        }),
    ],
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
    }

}
```

My Router.js

```
<Router history={history}>  
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" component={SignUpPage} exact={true} />
      <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
    <Switch>
<Router history={history}>
```

I think its something wrong in webpack config

Answer (score 1):

The last `Route` inside of the `Switch` is supposed to be for the "404 page" because none of the other route's paths didn't match

```js
<Router history={history}>  
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/" component={SignUpPage} exact={true} />
      <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
      <Route component={Your-404-Page} />
    <Switch>
<Router history={history}>
```

Here is an edited webpack config to test against. It has some bit of extra everything, you can take them out if you want

Just to make sure, have these packages installed as devDependencies (along with other required packages)

- webpack, webpack cli, webpack-dev-server
- style-loader, css-loader, sass-loader, postcss-loader, file-loader, autoprefixer

```js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

const DIST_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist');
const PUBLIC_DIR = DIST_DIR + '/public';

const rules = [
  {
    test: /\.t?j?sx?$/,
    exclude: '/node_modules/',
    use: ['babel-loader'],
  },
  {
    test: /\.s?css$/,
    use: [
      'style-loader',
      {
        loader: 'css-loader',
        options: {
          modules: true,
        },
      },
      'sass-loader',
      {
        loader: 'postcss-loader',
        options: {
          plugins: function () {
            return [require('autoprefixer')];
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    test: /\.(svg|png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/,
    use: {
      loader: 'file-loader',
      options: {
        name: '[name].[ext]',
        outputPath: `${PUBLIC_DIR}/assets/img`,
      },
    },
  },
  {
    test: /.(ttf|otf|eot|woff(2)?)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/,
    use: [
      {
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]',
          outputPath: `${PUBLIC_DIR}/assets/font`,
        },
      },
    ],
  },
];

module.exports = {
  target: 'web',
  entry: ['./src/index.js'],
  output: {
    path: DIST_DIR,
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  devtool: 'cheal-module-source-map',
  module: {
    rules,
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/index.html'),
    }),
  ],
  devServer: {
    compress: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: DIST_Dir,
    port: 3000,
    hot: true,
  },
};
```

Commands to start and build. This goes inside `package.json`

```js
    "scripts": {
        "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open",
        "build": "webpack --mode production"
    }
```

Here's an example .babelrc (It might not apply to you now, but if you're switching to typescript later on, here's an example)

If you don't have the packages, also install them as devDependencies

```js
{
    "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
    "env": {
        "development": {
            "presets": ["@babel/preset-typescript"]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah that's how I have it and it always give me the 404 page, even though it works okay on another project created with create-react-app cmd

Comment: I've added an example webpack config if you want to double check